# Display XML file from post request PHP - JAVA

Tags: java, php, xml

I have a wiered situation where I have to pass XML file from java client to PHP page.
PHP page will simply read the xml document from POST and display it using echo.
But I am not getting any output from my XML on PHP page when I use echo.
Here is my JAVA CLIENT:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/xml.php");
        String document = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\xml\\cars.xml";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(document);            
        char[] buffer = new char[1024*10];
        int bytes_read = 0;
        if ((bytes_read = fr.read(buffer)) != -1)
          {
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml");
            urlc.setDoOutput(true);
            urlc.setDoInput(true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(urlc.getOutputStream());

            // send xml to php
            pw.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
            pw.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                      System.out.println(inputLine);

            in.close();
            }              
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP page:

```
<?php
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);
echo $xmlData;
?>
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
<supercars company="Ferrari">
<carname type="formula one">Ferrari 101</carname>
<carname type="sports">Ferrari 202</carname></supercars>
</cars>
```

I got code of PHP to read XML from POST [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374224/how-to-receive-xml-requests-and-send-response-xml-in-php)
I would also like to parse xml file.
Please Help!!!

Comment: If you just need to echo it back you don't need to parse it. So what is it that **you actually need to do** with that xml?

Comment: $xmlData is an DOM object... I'm not sure you can even echo that.

Comment: i want to read data from that xml and display it using echo!!!